# Saving the values calculated in a list or a table

Tags: programming

I cannot realise if it is a duplicate question. Sorry; if it is.
This

```
fl[x0_] :=  Module[{x = 1}, While[x <= x0, If[Mod[x0, x] == 0, 
             Print[x]];   x++]]
```

print the factors of $x_0$. But a printed value cannot be reused. How to put those values in a list to reuse them. I have tried something like that

```
fl[x0_] := 
  Module[{x = 1 }, A = {}; 
  While[x <= x0, If[Mod[x0, x] == 0, Append[A, x] && Print[A]]; x++]]
```

but it return empty lists.

Comment: Maybe use `AppendTo` instead of `Append`.

Comment: Also you may want `FactorInteger`

Comment: Certainly, it would be the case if I was not only trying to understand the syntax. It's better to always use a predefined function.

Comment: FactorInteger doesn't give exactly the same result.

Comment: `Divisors@...` will be the fastest to accomplish goal, and should you feel the need to go through self-made machinations vs using a bult-in, `With[{r = Range@#}, Pick[r, Mod[#, r], 0]] &` will handily clobber the existing answers in performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach is to use `Table` combined with `Nothing` which is only available in version 10.2 or later.

```
f[x0_] := Table[If[Mod[x0, x] == 0, x, Nothing], {x, 1, x0}]
```

and then

```
fl[10]
(* {1, 2, 5, 10} *)
```

I found this to be slightly faster than using `Select` or the `Sow` and `Reap` approach.

Answer (score 7):

When you're processing an element at a time using procedural constructs like `Module`, `While`, `If`, and `Print` in *Mathematica*, it's usually a sign that you're fighting the language rather than using it. It's much easier and more concise to use functional constructs that work on arrays:

```
fl[x0_] := Select[Range[x0], Mod[x0, #] == 0 &]
```

Comment: You are perfectly right but I am learning and I was following a documentation posted on internet about modules. As I understand, it's better not to use it ?

Comment: You are perfectly right but I am learning and I was following a documentation posted on internet about modules. As I understand, it's better not to use it ? Also it is so compact, and clearly understandable.. But there is a drawback your solution take more tha 3% time than the one with AppendTo

Comment: Certainly it is not meant that *it is better not to use* `Module` in general. Specifically for this case it is not needed and one achieves a better performance with other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Use of "Sow" and "Reap" allow a simple modification of the existing code.  E.g.

```
fl[x0_] :=  Module[{x = 1}, While[x <= x0, If[Mod[x0, x] == 0, Sow[x]]; x++]]
```

and

```
Reap[fl[12]]
```

returns

```
{Null, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12}}}
```

Comment: This result is not the one I was expecting since it gives a sequence of an expending set not only the final one

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another version

```
fl[x0_] := Cases[Range[x0], y_ /; Mod[x0, y] == 0]
```

On my computer my version is slightly faster than everything else offered so far. In particular, I get the following `AbsoluteTiming` results on `fl[10000000]`:

1. "Cases": 9.4 sec
2. "Select": 9.8 sec
3. "Table": 10.8 sec
4. "AppendTo": 15.5 sec
5. "Sow": 15.6 sec

**Added:**  Using `Divisible[x0,x]` instead of `Mod[x0,x]==0`speeds up the computations 30-40%.

Comment: To precise a point : In the case of Table, one must add the deletion of Nothing to have a true comparable result. Nevertheless, Thanks to all the discutant, it was a very illuminating discussion